# trying to use sidr for two sidebars

Tags: jquery, sidr

I am using sidr with jquery to create two sidebars.  I can open the sidebars.  I am not trying to add list content in those sidebars.  However, when I add the div to my template, the content appears on the page.  I can use style display to none and block but was wondering if this is already included in sidr.

```
<div id="sidr">
  <!-- Your content -->
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">List 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">List 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I ended up using style="display:none;".

Comment: please provide fiddle

Comment: it is solved by adding style="display:none;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added "style="display:none;" to the div.  This allowed me to hide/display content with sidr.